# http authentication dialog not popping up

Tags: spring, http, security, authentication, redux

I'm trying to call(spring ) rest API which is protected using digest authentication using spring security and trying to access it from the redux front end. I'm getting a `401` response back to the front end, which has the response header WWW-Authenticate:  also .. but unfortunately I am not getting the http basic authentication pop in my front end to enter the username and password.

Can someone help me in identifying the possible reasons for this? I'm able to get the http authentication pop up when I hit my rest API directly through the chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, XHR requests do not trigger the auth pop-up. This will only happen if the main request (the html page you are loading or a redirect you make from that page) throws a 401.

The auth screen is also triggered if you load the request in an `iframe`. However, the credentials provided using the basic auth screen will not be passed on to other XHR requests. If you do use an iframe, you should respond with some sort of cookie and the subsequent XHR request should not need the basic auth screen again

Your options are:

1. Catch this error in your javascript and ask for the password using some interface you create yourself.
2. Make the same request in an iframe (or another request that will trigger the same security restriction) and respond with a session cookie upon success, then trigger the XHR.
3. Make an Login UI and ask for the credentials upfront, as you will need them for the XHR request.